# How to extract underscore containg hrefs from total hrefs using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i want to count href links which is containing underscore in link.

im using regex to find all hrefs but unable to get href which contains undersore character in the href

```
  MatchCollection hyperlinks = Regex.Matches(strIn, @"<(?<Tag_Name>(a)|img)\b[^>]*?\b(?<URL_Type>(?(1)href|src))\s*=\s*(?:""(?<URL>(?:\\""|[^""])*)""|'(?<URL>(?:\\'|[^'])*)')", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

exmple

```
<a href="http://hyderabad.yalwa.in/Building_Construction/G/"
```

Comment: I still believe you are following the wrong path of parsing HTML with regex. In your case, you really should think about switching to HtmlAgilityPack or similar parsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _len = $("a[href*='_']").length;
```

Use wildcard `*` to select all the `a` which have `_` in it's `href`

**Description:**

```
$("a") // Selects all elements with a tag

$("a[href='1234']") // Select all element with a tag whose href is exactly equals to 1234

$("a[href*='_']") // Select all element with a tag whose href contains string _
```

And as it return an array of mathched elements always, so `.length` will give you the count of it.

Comment: i didnt get it. can u little more describe.im using c#. server side code not js

Comment: @krishnamohan http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/6q97Lh0c/ .. while you tagged jquery .. this is a perfect answer  .. void you can use that demo in answer .. Its yours

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef :)

Answer (score 0):

Again, I do suggest using HtmlAgilityPack.

The only change to my previous method will be the XPath: `//a[contains(@href,'_')]`. It will get all `<a>` tags whose `href` attribute contains a `_` symbol.

See this code:

```
public int HtmlAgilityPackCountAwithUnderscore(string html)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
    Uri uriResult;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
    { // html is a URL 
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    else
    { // html is a string
        hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hap.LoadHtml(html);
    }
    var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href,'_')]");
    return nodes != null ? nodes.Count : -1;
}
```

I strongly advise switching to appropriate methods of HTML parsing, or you will lose lots of your precious time thinking about where you got wrong with a regex.